# Multiple instances of blueimp's jQuery File Upload with IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, upload, blueimp

I'm facing a weird situation using blueimp's jQuery File Upload.

My code is as simple as this:

```
<div><input type="file" name="files" id="f1"></div>
<div><input type="file" name="files" id="f2"></div>


<script>
$("input:file").each(function () {
    $(this).fileupload({
        url: "./?a=upload&t=",
        dataType: 'json',

        add: function (e, data) {
            alert("add");
            /* same as default implementation */
            if (data.autoUpload || (data.autoUpload !== false &&
                    $(this).fileupload('option', 'autoUpload'))) {
                data.process().done(function () {
                    data.submit();
                });
            }
        },

        start: function (e) {
            alert("start");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome: when clicking on any of the input fields the messages "add" and "start" are displayed and the request is submitted.
In IE 8 the two instances seem to be created (I get no error when loading the page), but when I click on a file input and choose a file to be uploaded, only the "add" message is displayed and then IE fires the error:

```
cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'process'
```

Having only one file input control in the page works fine, so I guess the issue must have something to do with multiple instances.

I'm using jQuery upload plugin 9.8.1 and jQuery 1.11.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the Demo page ([here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)) with IE8, it doesn't work (despite the demo page claims it should).

Comment: I have the same behaviour here, demo page does NOT work in IE 8